# CakePHP Form Validation Error Placement

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

Is there any way to change the placement of form validation messages in CakePHP? For instance, I have the following:

In the view:

```
echo $form->input('fname', array('before' => '<li>', 'label' => 'First Name', 'after' => '</li>'));
```

In the controller:

```
'fname' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty', 'message' => 'Please enter your first name.'),
```

This displays the error message next to the field, but is this enclosed in a DIV or is there a way to enclose the message in a DIV in order to improve its look/positioning?

I could not find anything about this in the documentation.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are a few basic things you can do by using the `error` option in $form->input. `wrap` will let you wrap the error in a different element type, and `class` lets you specify a class.

```
$form->input('fname', array('before' => '<li>', 'label' => 'First Name', 'after' => '</li>', 'error' => array('wrap' => 'div', 'class' => 'my-error-class')));
```

There's a bit more info about it in the Cookbook.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/198/options-error